# How to make simple table view using .xib or nib in iOS 6 and xcode 4.5?

Tags: uitableview, ios6

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    NSString *currentNames = [nameKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:currentNames];

    return cell;
   }
```

Why I am getting below error (I am using `.XIB` and not storyboards iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5).
I do have connected `datasource` and delegate from connection inspector ot files owner.

**Error :**

```
 Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:4460
    2012-12-27 11:35:45.146 TableViewWithXib[570:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Comment: See that from which class your view Controller is inherited ? ie. in .h file this kind of line `@interface YOURCLASSNAME : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>`

Comment: Yes i have confirmed to the protocol of <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> but the error remains the same

Comment: Then you must have one `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;` property defined and also in .XIB it is connected to `UITableView` instance. Then it will not give any error for sure as it never gives me any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

```
You must register a class or nib file using the 
registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: 
method before calling,
```

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Therefore, if you aren't doing that with a nib file, then using

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

i.e; without the `forIndexPath:indexPath` would also work.